# Generic UITableViewCell with Different Kind Of JSON data

Tags: ios, swift

I like to use a **single tableViewCell** instance (instead creating separate cells) for different kind of data; used a simple generic approach by creating a protocol for this but how can I populate data from JSON (by avoiding switch-case) in clear way?

```
protocol CellData {
    var title: String { get set }
    var subTitle: String { get set }
    var image: String { get set }
}
```

for the singleCell

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "company",
      "data": {
        "name": "Google",
        "sector": "IT",
        "logo": "https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.3-hp2x.gif"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "person",
      "data": {
        "name": "Bill Gates",
        "occupation": "Microsoft CEO",
        "picture": "https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-66398917,width-640,resizemode-4,imgsize-702055/words-of-wisdom.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "song",
      "data": {
        "name": "Beat It",
        "singer": "M.Jackson",
        "thumbnail": "https://cdn.smehost.net/michaeljacksoncom-uslegacyprod/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Sept2019Mobile.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "vehicle",
      "data": {
        "name": "Silver Silver",
        "brand": "Silver",
        "photo": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/112460/pexels-photo-112460.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
      }
    }
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

Comment: At some point you have to use a logic to distinguish the types, either while decoding the JSON or at the latest in `cellForRow`.

Comment: Types will be a struct to separate logic also used a viewModel cellForRow setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have guarantees about the keys that you can expect, then you could try to parse the data for the first key that is found:

```swift
struct CellDataEnvelope: Decodable {
  let data: CellData
  let type: CellDataType

  enum CellDataType: String, Decodable {
    case company
    case person
    case song
    case vehicle
  }
}

struct CellData: Decodable {
  let title: String
  let subTitle: String
  let image: String

  enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    // title
    case name

    // subTitle
    case sector
    case occupation
    case singer
    case brand

    // image
    case thumbnail
    case picture
    case logo
    case photo
  }
}

extension CellData {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)

    self.subTitle = try tryDecodeString(in: container, keys: [.sector, .occupation, .singer, .brand])
    self.image = try tryDecodeString(in: container, keys: [.thumbnail, .picture, .logo, .photo])
  }
}

// Attempts to decode a String value from an array of keys, returns the first one to successfully decode.
private func tryDecodeString(
  in container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CellData.CodingKeys>,
  keys: [CellData.CodingKeys]
) throws -> String {
  for key in keys {
    if let value = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: key) {
      return value
    }
  }

  throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
    .init(
      codingPath: [],
      debugDescription: "Invalid data"
    )
  )
}


let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([CellDataEnvelope].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
```

This could become unwieldy if the list of keys will grow substantially or if you don't have guarantees about them.

Comment: Yes, It gives me idea. Also I added `decodeIfPresent` while decoding. I have a list of guaranteed keys (whitelisted) it will work and of course you are right about substantially growing keys need to be handle. Thank you @jwswart

Answer (score 0):

You can have a model with optional attributes, which means they won't always need to have all of the properties setted, but as mentioned by Vadian, at some point you will need to map what you are receiving.

You can also define all of your keys that are not image or title, as the subtitle (for example, sector or occupation or singer or brand).